# Potential Difference between 2 points

Tags: resistance

I am new to electrical engineering and I know almost absolutely nothing, but I am working on it by doing some practice questions that I found online. I am at 2 questions, which are:

Find the total resistance of the circuit and potential difference between points A and B

I've done the first questions, finding the total resistance of the circuit but I'm not sure that I've done it right. Any help would be great .

I've done:=R1+R2+R3+R4 because circuit is in series right ?
40Ω+60Ω+120Ω+40Ω=260Ω
[image]

Comment: it is unclear what `total resistance of the circuit` actually means ... resistance would be measured between two points ... the only way to have all four resistors in series, is to break the circuit at any node

Answer (score 1):

Think of +ve terminal as starting point and -ve terminal as ending point for the current. For the first question, there are two ways current can reach end from the start: through R1 and R2 and through R3 and R4. Since the current divides, upper segment is in parallel with lower segment.

For upper segment consisting of R1 and R2, same current flows through both R1 and R2. So they are in series. Same is the case with lower segment.

I want you to figure out the remaining calculations.